# Outlook stripping inline image

Tags: html, outlook

Working in the Outlook space I've begun to notice some users are experiencing an issue where when they attach an inline image and send it the user receiving the email doesn't see the image.

So say a user sends:

```html
<img id="m_redacted_xredacted" src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/redacted_redactedXredacted#https://t.redacted.com/redacted/redacted/thing.gif" class="CToWUd">
```

It becomes stripped/replaced/manipulated and appears as:

```html
<img id="m_-<redacted>_x<redacted>" src="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0?ui=random-ids" 
data-image-whitelisted="" 
class="CToWUd">
```

Which translates to some odd white 40x40 square "Image001.png" from, Show Original:

```html
<img id=3D"_x0000_i1026" src==3D"cid:image001.png@01D7048B.91284660">
```

Could this be an Outlook setting on the users end where inline images to certain URL's are rejected. Where it replaces an inline image `src` or something larger entirely?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, your example image ```thing.gif``` return a 400, appart from that, the outlook client has a setting to block all images that aren't from known source, the users have to select the option ```download images from this sender```. I'm not sure if that's your case since the example doesn't work, but it looks like that

Comment: Thanks Mathieu, I'm aware it will return a 400, it is not a real path however just an example. I can't share the real path due to privacy reasons. So this is an issue with sending not with receiving. If I open this email on Gmail I will see this `image001.png`